# Hadoop- MapReduce - FixedInputFormat: java.io.IOException: Partial record found at the end of split

Tags: java, mapreduce, hadoop2

Could you suggest to resolve the error that appears in FixedInputFormat while running MapReduce: `Partial record found at the end of split`

I am analysing to customize `FileInputFormat` for Hive and was studying the `FixedInputFormat` from the below github:
    https://github.com/apache/hadoop/tree/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input

I copied both the `FixedInputFormat` and `FixedRecordReader` and, created a Mapper and Driver program to test this (0 reducer).

In the Mapper called this FixedInputFormat as below:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration(true);
conf.set("fs.default.name", "file:///");
conf.setInt("fixedlengthinputformat.record.length",50);
job.setInputFormatClass(FixedLengthInputFormat.class);
```

The data file looks like below(testing with 3 records):

> ```
>    000yyy022222222xxxxxxx                       11111
> ```

The splitsize is calculating as 152 instead of 150 and I get the below error:

> java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException: Partial record(length = 2) found at the end of split.
>   INFO customFixed.FixedLengthRecordReader: Expecting 4 records each with a length of 50 bytes in the split with an effective size of 152 bytes

I am running this from Intellij in windows for analysis.

Is there anything wrong in the approach?
Could you suggest to resolve this error and I would be grateful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the code of FixedInputFormat as provided in the github.

The basic criteria is that each record should be of the same length. 
What it means is each record in your file should be of length "fixedlengthinputformat.record.length" each.

Please verify the input file, I am sure that one of your record is more than 50 to be precise 52

Record Reader is reading 50 bytes at a time and in the end if left with 2 bytes, which it is not being able to interpret as a valid record.

Comment: I tried with a different input file(this time txt) with only 3 records each with 50 length and now it reads as 
mapred.MapTask: Processing split: file:/C:anaCommon/src/main/resources/Input1.txt:0+154   - 4 bytes in partial records

Comment: I am expecting 150

Comment: can you please make 49 as record length and \n as 50th. Please make sure you dont have any extra \n on 4th line. 

If using some text editor please make sure the delimiter is appropriate .


https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/FixedLengthRecordReader.java 


Please check there is no special treatment for delimeter, it is considered as part of your record.

Comment: You can event set 51 as fixedlengthinputformat.record.length and remove \n from the 4th line.     use wc -c fileName to see how many characters are present in file it will count \n also hence providing you the right number.

Comment: Thanks KrazyGautam. This is what I was thinking about. Let me try in Unix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157887/discussion-between-aavik-and-krazygautam).